# Finding the positions of 2 points in a simple 2D geometric configuration

Tags: geometry

I have the following configuration:

[image: Imgur]

- I know the coordinates of the points in black and I need the coordinates of the ones in red.
- L is also fixed and $> 0$.
- $CD$ is the bisector of $\widehat{ECF}$ (which I don't know the angle value)

**edit:**

I have started with the following equation system assuming

- $\textbf{ab}$ and $\textbf{cd}$ are unit length vectors
- $R$ is the 2x2 rotation matrix of angle $\theta = \frac{\widehat{ECF}}{2}$, $R = \begin{vmatrix}\cos \theta & - \sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta \\\end{vmatrix}$
- $\textbf{cd}_{left} = R \textbf{cd}$
- $\textbf{cd}_{right} = R^T \textbf{cd}$

$\begin{cases}
E = \textbf a + t \cdot \textbf{ab} & = & \textbf c + u \cdot \textbf{cd}_{left} \\
F = \textbf a + (t+L) \cdot \textbf{ab} & = & \textbf c + v \cdot \textbf{cd}_{right} \\
\end{cases}$

The unkown being $\theta$, $t$, $u$ and $v$. Am I on the right path?

Comment: Do you have any kind of solution to this problem? If not (i.e. it's not homework or anything similar), I would say you are missing at least one parameter to get a uniquely determined solution, unless you are to construct one for an arbitrary angle in ECF...

Comment: @SDV Increase the angle at C, then E and F move farther apart. Thus, EF should be a strictly increasing function of the angle, and I would take "EF=L" as indication that this length is given.

Comment: L is given, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that you're not on the right path, in the sense that picking "cd" to be a unit vector might not be consistent with "ab" being a unit vector.

If I were solving this, I'd start by applying a rotation to the whole situation to make $ab$ horizontal. (How? Let $(x, y) = b - a$; rotate by $atan2(-y, x)$); then I'd translate everything so that $C$ was at the origin. So now the problem becomes this:

Given a point $D= (x, y)$ in the plane, and the line $y = h$, find the angle $\theta$ such that rays from the origin $C$ to the left and right of $D$ by angle $\theta$ meet the line $y = h$ at points $E$ and $F$ whose $x$-coordinates differ by the known value $L$.

Now the only unknown you're solving for is $\theta$.

My guess is that the answer will be messy.

As a practical matter, bisection is likely to converge to an approximately correct answer very quickly.

Ooops: my guess was wrong. Assuming that the point $(x, y)$ (after my transformations) is in the first quadrant, compute
$$
\phi = atan2(x, y),
$$
the angle between the ray from $C$ to $D$ and the positive-$y$ axis. Suppose you are given $\theta$. Then the angle from the ray $CE$ to the $y$-axis is $\phi - \theta$, and the angle from $CF$ to the $y$-axis is $\phi + \theta$; that means that the $x$-coordinates of $E$ and $F$ are just
$$
x_E = h \tan(\phi-\theta) \\
x_F = h \tan(\phi+\theta).
$$

Now $$
\tan(a+b) = \frac{ \tan a + \tan b } {1 - \tan a \tan b} \text{ and} \\
\tan(a-b) = \frac{ \tan a - \tan b } {1 + \tan a \tan b}  
$$
so $x_F - x_E$ is $h$ times 
$$
\frac{ \tan \phi + \tan \theta } {1 - \tan \phi \tan \theta} 
-\frac{ \tan  \phi - \tan \theta } {1 + \tan \phi \tan \theta}  
$$

You can now replace $\tan \phi$ with $\frac{x}{y}$, and set the expression above to $L/h$ and solve for $\tan \theta$. That'll be a little messy, but if my scratch work is right, you'll end up with a quadratic in $\tan \theta$, whose two solutions are negatives of each other; you'll want to pick the positive one, take its arctan, and you'll have $\theta$.

Comment: where does the  $2 \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ come from? Shouldn't there be a L somewhere?

Comment: It came from a mistaken reading of the problem. It should be replaced with $L$, which I'll do shortly in the answer.

Comment: Great! I'll try to implement this.

Comment: If $\phi = 0$, $\theta = \tan^{-1}(\frac{L}{2h})$. Else $\theta = \left\{ \tan^{-1}(\frac{-1 - A^2 - \sqrt{1+2A^2+a^4+a^2B^2}}{A^2B}),
\tan^{-1}(\frac{-1 - A^2 + \sqrt{1+2A^2+a^4+a^2B^2}}{A^2B}) \right\}$ with $A = \frac{x}{y}$ and $B = \frac{L}{h}$.